# How to change the string to timestamp in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to change a string to a time_stamp in pyspark(Spark version =2.3.0) with below data set and api

I have been trying with different resolution from stack overflow, but nothing could help to change to the time_stamp

```py
df:
|Customer|Transaction_Timestamp|Transaction_Base_Point_Value|
+--------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|Cust1   |10/25/2017 1:47      |2000                        |
```

## Attempt 1

```py
df2 = df.select('Customer', 'Transaction_Timestamp','Transaction_Base_Point_Value', unix_timestamp('Transaction_Timestamp', "dd/MM/yy HH:mm") .cast(TimestampType()).alias("Timestamp")).show(1, False)
```

## Attempt 2

```py
df.withColumn('Time', to_timestamp("Transaction_Timestamp", "yyyy_MM_dd hh_mm_ss").cast("Timestamp"))
```

## Attempt 3

```py
change_type= df.withColumn('Timestamp', col='Transaction_Timestamp').cast('timestamp')
```

However, the schema produces the following output

```py
 |-- Timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I need to get the output as follows, so that i can perform other operation on timestamp

```py
|Customer|Transaction_Timestamp|Transaction_Base_Point_Value|Timestamp|
+--------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+
|   Cust1|      10/25/2017 1:47|                        2000|     10/25/2017 1:47|
```

Answer (score -1):

use `to_timestamp` from `pyspark.sql.functions`

```
.withColumn('Timestamp', to_timestamp('Transaction_Timestamp', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm'))
```

also a padded hour value would be nice to have not `1:47` but `01:47`

Comment: Hi Kendoka, Thanks for your replay. However the above solution didn't worked for me. Timestamp still throw Null values even the schema got changed.

Comment: you can try `col("Transaction_Timestamp").cast("Timestamp")` I wonder if zero padded time string would change things...